# Replacing a long list of Sieve rules with a generic rule

Tags: email, email-filter, sieve-rules, sieve

I have a couple of Sieve rules like this:

```
if header :contains "To" "shop1@domain.tld" 
{
    fileinto "shops/shop1" ;
}

[...]

if header :contains "To" "shopN@domain.tld" 
{
    fileinto "shops/shopN" ;
}

[...]

if header :contains "To" "service1@domain.tld"
{
    fileinto "services/service1" ;
}

[...]

if header :contains "To" "serviceN@domain.tld" 
{
    fileinto "services/serviceN" ;
}
```

`shop1` to `shopN` are replaced with names of actual shops etc.

Instead of having these long list of almost identical rules, I would like to specify a list of strings (or what ever is the Sieve equivalent) like this:

```
shops="shop1","shop2","shopN"
services="service1","service2","serviceN"
```

**I'm looking for a generic rules that filters my emails based the above lists of strings.**
Can I do that with Sieve? What extensions do I need?

I considered writing an external script that generates the sieve rules for me but I don't like this approach.

Comment: Which sieve implementation do you run?  There are extension to do it if you use "bleeading edge" and do not care much about portability.

Comment: I'm using the implementation that https://mailbox.org provides. I don't expect them to support bleeding edge extensions that aren't standardised. What extensions are we talking about in particular?

Comment: https://wiki.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Plugins/Extdata